# replace multiple values in a string with multiple sources

Tags: php

I have a pixel like:

```
<img src='http://www.montag.com/directory_folder/tracking_noip.php?tracking=[ID_MTG]&data=[TEL]' height='1' width='1' border='0'/>
```

I need to replace the keys [TEL] and [ID_MTG] with the value I receive from a script.  For example if I have:

```
$tel = "0613321223";
$id_mtg = "4875";
$email = "thatmail@gmail.com";
```

I need to output:

```
<img src='http://www.montag.com/directory_folder/tracking_noip.php?tracking=4875&data=0613321223' height='1' width='1' border='0'/>
```

If I have:

```
<img src='http://www.montag.com/directory_folder/tracking_noip.php?tracking=[ID_MTG]&data=[EMAIL]' height='1' width='1' border='0'/>
```

I need to ouput:

```
<img src='http://www.montag.com/directory_folder/tracking_noip.php?tracking=4875&data=thatmail@gmail.com' height='1' width='1' border='0'/>
```

I have:

```
$tel = "0613357221";
$email = "Chachachou@gmail.com";
$id_mtg = "560";

$string = "<img src='http://www.montag.com/directory_folder/tracking_noip.php?tracking=[TEL]&data=[ID_MTG]' height='1' width='1' border='0'/>";
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = ' /\[TEL\]/ ';
$patterns[1] = ' /\[EMAIL\]/ ';
$patterns[2] = ' /\[ID_MTG\]/ ';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = $id_mtg;
$replacements[1] = $email;
$replacements[0] = $tel;
echo htmlentities(preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string));
```

But my string is:

```
<img src='http://www.montag.com/directory_folder/tracking_noip.php?tracking=520&data=0613357221' height='1' width='1' border='0'/>
```

The order is reversed.

Comment: I don't see the need for regular expressions if you search for fixed strings. Have you tried [strtr](http://php.net/strtr)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is wrong because you defined your `$replacements` in reverse order. Even though you specified indexes in descending order, **the order in which you created the array is preserved**.  Check this with `print_r($replacements);`.  You could sort by keys with `ksort()` if needed to get the array in the proper order.

But for this application, `strtr()` or `str_replace()` makes more sense.  Make sure to define the arrays in the same order:

```
$search  = array('[TEL]', '[EMAIL]', '[ID_MTG]');
$replace = array($tel, $email, $id_mtg);

$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: I look at this solution after the train but it seems to me perfectly do the trick! I think i search too far ^^

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'hi all, I said hello';

$replace_pairs = array(
  'all' => 'everybody',
  'hello' => 'hey',
);

echo strtr($str, $replace_pairs);
```

This would help you.